# Special characters do not appear in android Api level 19

Tags: android, unicode, special-characters

I am creating an app which is in `nepali/hindi` language. But those texts are not supported/seen in the devices with api level 19. It does not work in both ways i.e when i try to set text direct from `xml` or programatically.

```
txt2.setText("कर्मचारी");
```

I even tried to call the string putting it on `string.xml`, still it does not work.

```
txt2.setText(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.myCharacter));
```

the text does not appear. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: use utf8 and also probably you need supporting font also

Comment: Does your font have those characters?

Comment: getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.myCharacter) you can try this

Comment: Your testing device should support hindi/nepali as display language in phone settings i.e. Settings -> Language

Answer (score 0):

Your test device should support hindi or nepali (font) as display language in phone settings i.e. Settings -> Language & Input -> Change Language.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answer guys. However i found a suitable one for me. I created an asset folder>Font and inside it i pasted the ttf file that i required. And after that simply I wrote the required unicod ein xml's text. Then i called it by using typeface as

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/aparaj.ttf");
    txt2.setTypeface(typeface);
```

This worked for me as i wanted.

Answer (score -1):

1.Change your default font by adding a font resource(more info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)) and in style.xml, under AppTheme, add that font
style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/fontName</item>
</style>
```

2.If that doesn't work, use a real device, instead emulator.